# Annotation Value is not working in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I want to read few values from properties file through @Value annotation, but getting error.

Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'rcm.datasource.driverClassName' in value "${rcm.datasource.driverClassName}"`

**properties file**

```
rcm.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**java class**

```
@Configuration
public class RcmDBConfig {

    @Value("${rcm.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

@Bean(name = "rcmEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean productEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

      System.out.println(driverClassName);

}

}
```

Comment: what is the location of your properties file. Is it in the classpath.. ?

Comment: yes, its in the classpath...inside resources folder

Comment: Name of the properties file is application.properties right.. ?

Comment: yes, same name application.properties

Comment: Hi All, its resolved now, that piece of code is perfectly fine....eclipse had some issue. 
Thanks all for ur time

Answer (score 0):

The value can be able to inject if you have specified the component-scan package properly; otherwise spring boot can't be able to detect the packages for auto-configuration.
Ex:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.deb.xyz.*"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and your `RcmDBConfig.java` must be in package like `com.deb.xyz.config`

Comment: is there any need of @ComponentScan ?? because i am following the project package structure.  This RcmDBConfig is in the child package.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```java
@Configuration
public class MyDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
```

here is the yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: ****
    password: ***********
    jdbc-url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myshema?autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPools=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&serverTimezone=UTC
```

or you just want to read yml or properties files in java class
the like this

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
@Getter
@Setter
public class SpringYMLData {

    private String driver-class-name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String jdbc-url;
}
```